# Where does less store history of search patterns?

Tags: less

Let's say I open a file with `less` and look for a pattern such as
`/time=32`, then exit with `q`, and maybe run other commands. Then, if
I open the same file again with `less` and hit `n` to repeat the last
pattern sought, `less` remembers it from the first time `less` was
called.

How is the pattern saved after exiting `less` for the first time?
where is it saved?

PS: I am using bash on Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Tip: if the man page and Google don't have the answer to this sort of question, you can see what's changed most recently by going to your home directory and using `ls -ltra`. (Or `ls -lart` if you're a BOFH.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The pattern is saved in `$HOME/.lesshst` which contains something like:

```
.less-history-file:
.search
"journal
"67
"link
```

A command is preceded by '**.**' (dot) an the argument is preceded by '**"**' (double quotes), so if I edit by hand the `.lesshst` file to append for example the string **"TEST**:

```
.less-history-file:
.search
"journal
"67
"link
"TEST
```

the next time I'll open a file and press `n` key, `less` will search for the string "TEST".

Answer (score 8):

According to the less man page, the default location for the history
file is `~/.lesshst`:

```
LESSHISTFILE

     Name of the history file used to remember  search  commands  and
     shell  commands  between  invocations of less.  If set to "-" or
     "/dev/null", a  history  file  is  not  used.   The  default  is
     "$HOME/.lesshst"  on  Unix  systems, "$HOME/_lesshst" on DOS and
     Windows systems, or "$HOME/lesshst.ini"  or  "$INIT/lesshst.ini"
     on OS/2 systems.
```